# Unexpected True Value as output in Palindrome

Tags: python

I write such a problem to solve Palindrome problem

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        import re
        s1 = re.findall(r"[a-z]", s.lower())
        s2 = list(reversed(s1))        
        logging.debug(f"s1: {s1}, s2:{s2}, {s1==s2}")
        return s1 == s2
```

Run the test  and succeed

```
$ python 125.ValidPalindrome_str_easy.py MyCase.test_c
DEBUG s1: ['o', 'p'], s2:['p', 'o'], False
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

but in leetcode

[image]

It's impossible the program will output a True.

Comment: Please _delete_ your Leetcode screen capture and instead include text, formatted as code by adding four or more spaces to each line.  If you want others to spend time helping you, expect to invest at least a few minutes into formatting your question.

Comment: That screen grab looks more like "zero" than like "oh".

Comment: You're only checking if the letters `a-z` in a string are a palindrome, the test is `0P` not `OP`. So when you remove the numbers, `0P` -> `P` which is a palindrome.

Comment: The debug log seems good. Why would it return `True` :/

Comment: could you please transmit it comment to answer @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not actually producing palindromes, that is why the test has failed.

See this step through:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = "0P"
In [3]: re.findall(r"[a-z]", s.lower())
Out[3]: ['p']                             # This is `s1`
In [4]: list(reversed(_))
Out[4]: ['p']                             # This is `s2`
```

As you can see they are the same. Because the regex being used has removed numeric (`0-9`) characters. You are only looking at the characters `a-z`, if you were to just reverse the string without using `re` then you would be fine.

---

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

This works by slicing the string with a step of -1, to reverse it.

```
In [6]: is_palindrome("0P")
Out[6]: False
In [7]: is_palindrome("madam")
Out[7]: True
```